# Making advance search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have one field in my database : `xfield`
This field has the following format for my posts(products) in website :

```
weight|3kg|year|2009|brand|samsung|monitorsize|13"|modem|yes
```

Now I want to perform an advance search. For example I want to search monitor sizes between 13" ~ 15"
and weight between 1.5kg ~ 3.5kg

How can I make that search page with php?

Comment: What datatype are the 2 columns ? im guessing they are varchar or text ?

Comment: If you want to search in it, I advice you to split this data up in multiple columns. Otherwise searching it will be slow and not so easy..

Comment: Fixed format columns aren't very suitable to be queried against variable ranges. Create a view that expands that into a key:value table again.

Comment: What do you gain with such a database schema?

Comment: You should rethink your design of that database since every time you insert that CSV data into it God kills a kitten.

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem i`m using datalifeengine cms, and i cant change it...

Answer (score 1):

You are using CSV data in a database, this is a really really bad idea, that will make you bold (insert random picture of person pulling out hair here).
Never use CSV in databases, it's an anti-pattern.

Instead what you need to do is to refactor your DB design to only put one value in one field.
I'm guessing you want to be as flexible as possible.
In that case use `entity-attribute-value` model (EAV).

Your table should look like:

```
table properties (

id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
product_id unsigned integer,
attribute varchar(20) not null,    
astring varchar(100),
anumber decimal(10,2),
atype enum('string','integer','boolean','float'),
unit varchar(10) not null,
foreign key (product_id) references product(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key (attribute) references attribute(name) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key (unit) references unit(name) on update cascade on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

table unit (
name varchar(10) primary key -- "kg","inch",.......
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

table attribute (
name varchar(20) primary key -- allowed name for the attribute  
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The links to the external tables ensure that your units and attributes are selected from a limited pool of consistent identifiers.

Now you can query your DB using something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM product p
INNER JOIN properties ps1 ON (ps1.product_id = p.id)
INNER JOIN properties ps2 ON (ps2.product_id = p.id)
WHERE ps1.attribute = 'monitorsize' AND ps1.anumber BETWEEN 13 AND 15
WHERE ps2.attribute = 'weight' AND ps2.anumber BETWEEN 1.5 AND 3.5
```

Comment: i`m using datalifeengine cms and really i cant edit xfield sector of this cms.
there is no way?
thanks for above answers.